Use CHOOSE function with range in Google Sheets
I would like to use CHOOSE function with a range (that can changed over time).
How can I do that ?
Currently, it's not working as I get an error message:

"Function CHOOSE parameter 1 value is 2. Valid values are between 1 and 1 inclusive.".

It seems to me that CHOOSE function is interpreting A2:A7 as a single parameter.

The result should be like so, but without having to list explicitly all the cells:


How would you like to use the CHOOSE function in the first place? Why not use INDEX instead of CHOOSE?

I.e. =INDEX(A2:A7,3)

Unfortunately, there's no equivalent of the spread-syntax in Google sheets formula language, which allows you to spread the range into multiple arguments to a function. You may use CHOOSEROWS or CHOOSECOLS instead, which accepts a range.
